# AssertionError: error message must contain revert

Tags: token, ethereum, solidity, revert

While I run test I get this error..

I am trying to make my own cryptocurrency using the DAPPuniversity tutorial, however, my code keeps throwing an exception.

```
  Contract: ValleyToken
    √ initialize the contract with correct values (363ms)
    √ sets the initial supply upon deployment (363ms)
    1) transfers token ownership
    > No events were emitted


  2 passing (869ms)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: ValleyToken
       transfers token ownership:
     ReferenceError: Faicoin is not defined
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\ValleyToken.js:47:5)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this code with your test : )

```
   it("transfers token ownership", function () {
        return ValleyToken.deployed()
          .then(function (instance) {
            tokenInstance = instance;
            return tokenInstance.transfer.call(accounts[1], 9999999999999999);
          })
          .then(assert.fail)
          .catch(function (error) {
            assert(error.message, "error message must contain revert");
            return tokenInstance.transfer.call(accounts[1], 250000, {
              from: accounts[0],
            });
          })
          .then(function (success) {
            assert(success, true, "it returns true");
            return tokenInstance.transfer(accounts[1], 250000, {
              from: accounts[0],
            });
          })
          .then(function (receipt) {
            assert.equal(receipt.logs.length, 1, "triggers one event");
            assert.equal(
              receipt.logs[0].event,
              "Transfer",
              'should be the "Transfer" event'
            );
            assert.equal(
              receipt.logs[0].args._from,
              accounts[0],
              "logs the account the tokens are transferred from"
            );
            assert.equal(
              receipt.logs[0].args._to,
              accounts[1],
              "logs the account the tokens are transferred to"
            );
            assert.equal(
              receipt.logs[0].args._value,
              250000,
              "logs the transfer amount"
            );
            return tokenInstance.balanceOf(accounts[1]);
          })
          .then(function (reciept) {
            return tokenInstance.balanceOf(accounts[1]);
          })
          .then(function (balance) {
            assert.equal(
              balance.toNumber(),
              250000,
              "adds the amount to the recieving amount"
            );
            return tokenInstance.balanceOf(accounts[0]);
          })
          .then(function (balance) {
            assert.equal(
              balance.toNumber(),
              750000,
              "deducts the amount from the sending account"
            );
          });
      });
```

Comment: in `assert(error.message, "error message must contain revert");` why is `error.message` the condition for this assertion?

Answer (score 0):

Completing my transfer function solved this issue for me.

```
it("transfers tokens ownership", function() {
    return HanuToken.deployed().then(function(tok) {
      var token = tok;
      return token.transfer.call(accounts[1], 99999999999999);
    }).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error) {
        assert(error.message.toString().indexOf('revert') >=0, 'error msg must contains revert');
    });
});
```

See below implementation.

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;

    return true;
}
```